# Derivative of Parametric Integral Using Leibniz

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$F(x)=\int_{3-x}^{x^2}\frac{\sin(4xy)}{y}dy$$

I need to find $F' \left(\frac 3 2 \right)$

The integrand is continuous in $\left[\frac 3 2, \frac 9 4 \right]$ so I tried Leibniz with chain rule and it turned into an extremely long expression. Is there a simpler, more elegant way of calculating this? Thank you.

Comment: Make a variable substitution if it is too difficult as is.

Comment: How would a substitution help (I assume you mean of the limits of integration)?

Comment: It removes the integrands dependence on x. Set $t = 4xy \implies dt = 4x dy$ and change the limits etc. Then you end up with $$F = \int_{12x-4x^{2}}^{4x^{3}} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt$$ which you can easily apply the Leibniz rule to.